# Change hover message in ggplotly map

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I've managed to plot a map where each municipality is filled with a different color depending on the value of a column in the data frame. This is the code I'm using for the plot:

```
mapa_df2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black",aes(fill = nivel1)) +
  coord_map("mercator") +
  labs(title = "Day 1 level map") +
  scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=c("green","yellow","orange","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                       breaks=c(0,1,2,3),labels=c("Normal","Moderado","Alto","Extremo"),
                       limits=c(0,3))
```

Now I'm trying to convert to an interactive map with plotly.

```
p <- mapa_df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, text = nombre)) +
  geom_path(data=mapa.prov_df2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color="blue", size=1.5) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white",aes(fill = nivel1)) +
  coord_map("mercator") +
  labs(title = "Day 1 level map") +
  scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=c("green","yellow","orange","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                       breaks=c(0,1,2,3),labels=c("Normal","Moderado","Alto","Extremo"),
                       limits=c(0,3)) 


ggplotly(p, width = 748, height = 1024, tooltip = "text")
```

Then I get an error message: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'nombre' not found` but `nombre` is one of the columns in data frame `mapa_df2`, it actually exists.

I would like that the name of the municipality appears when the mouse is over. If I remove `text=nombre` from the code above then I get `trace: value` in the hover message. For sure there is a mistake in the `tooltip` or `text=`. Any hint or idea will be very welcome.

Output of `head(mapa_df2)`

```
        long      lat   order  hole piece          id         group nombre_municipio c_autonoma provincia municipio zona  nombre
1 -0.1963169 38.85944 2421544 FALSE     1 34100303001 34100303001.1       l'AtzÃºbia         10        03     03001   20 Adsubia
2 -0.1959364 38.86003 2421545 FALSE     1 34100303001 34100303001.1       l'AtzÃºbia         10        03     03001   20 Adsubia
3 -0.1957341 38.86049 2421546 FALSE     1 34100303001 34100303001.1       l'AtzÃºbia         10        03     03001   20 Adsubia
4 -0.1957434 38.86084 2421547 FALSE     1 34100303001 34100303001.1       l'AtzÃºbia         10        03     03001   20 Adsubia
5 -0.1976370 38.86632 2421548 FALSE     1 34100303001 34100303001.1       l'AtzÃºbia         10        03     03001   20 Adsubia
6 -0.1939176 38.86917 2421549 FALSE     1 34100303001 34100303001.1       l'AtzÃºbia         10        03     03001   20 Adsubia
  nivel1 nivel2 nivel3
1      1      1      1
2      1      1      1
3      1      1      1
4      1      1      1
5      1      1      1
6      1      1      1
```

**EDIT 1**
As the output of dput was too large, just added a link to sample data used in the script
[Link to sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qloaxclqslwt72/CSV_data.csv?dl=0)

**EDIT 2**
Graphical output. Where the label says 'trace 0' I would like to replace with the column `nombre` which would show the name of the municipality.

[image]

**EDIT 3**
As @stefan said, running without the call `geom_path` and with some changes the `ggplot` runs fine

```
p <- mapa_df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = nivel1,
                       text = nombre)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white") +
  coord_map("mercator") +
  scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=c("green","yellow","orange","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                       breaks=c(0,1,2,3),labels=c("Normal","Moderado","Alto","Extremo"),
                       limits=c(0,3))
```

But now I need to find how to overlay `mapa_prov.df2` without affecting the `hover`

**EDIT 4**
Link to data in `mapa_prov.df2` [mapa_prov.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mw0g6q82s9mytdx/mapa_prov.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(head(mapa_df2))`.

Comment: How about your second df `mapa.prov_df2`? is `nombre` also a column of this dataset?

Comment: @stefan Yes `nombre` is a column in the dataset. It is the name of the municipality I would like to show when the mouse is over, filled with the color of the polygon.

Comment: When I run your code without the `geom_polygon` (which uses `mapa.prov_df2`) it works fine. I don't get any errors. As you haven't provided the second dataset I guessed that this second dataset does not include a column named `nombre` which will raise the same error message you got.

Comment: Yes, the second data set is the provincial border just to overlay. The error message I get is `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'nombre' not found`. If I remove ` text = nombre` from the ggplot it works fine but the tooltip shows `trace : value`, being value o to 3 the value assigned to each polygon. map_prov.df2 can be removed from the plot, it has nothing to do with the tooltip issue, I think.

Comment: @stefan just added a graph to show the result I'm getting now where I would like to show `nombre`

Comment: Hi pacomet. Maybe it's a different issue. But I'm quite sure that the issue is related to `map_prov.df2`. When I exclude the 'geom_path` your code runs fine on my machine and gives me a tooltip with the name of the province. The same is true if I simply replace `map_prov.df2` by `map.df`. Unfortunately I could not check that as you provide no information about this dataset.

Comment: @stefan added link to csv file for `mapa_prov.df2`. nombre variable is not present here, related to the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(: "nombre variable is not present here"? That was the question I asked in my first comment and the reason for the error. Every variable which you put in `ggplot(aes(...))`  has to be present in **each** dataframe, i.e. these are global aesthetics. Hence, you get an error message when adding `mapa_prov.df2` as ggplot2 looks for a variable `nombre` in this dataset too. To prevent that you have to make `text` a local aes of the `geom_polygon`, i.e. do `geom_polygon(color = "white",aes(fill = nivel1, text=nombre))`.

```
library(plotly) 

mapa_df2 <- readr::read_csv("CSV_data.csv")
mapa.prov_df2 <- readr::read_csv("mapa_prov.csv")

ggplot(mapa_df2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_path(data= mapa.prov_df2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color="blue", size=1.5) +
  geom_polygon(color = "white",aes(fill = nivel1, text = nombre)) +
  coord_map("mercator") +
  labs(title = "Day 1 level map") +
  scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=c("green","yellow","orange","red"),na.value = "transparent",
                       breaks=c(0,1,2,3),labels=c("Normal","Moderado","Alto","Extremo"),
                       limits=c(0,3)) 


ggplotly(width = 748, height = 1024, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Comment: That was my mistake, thought the data frame were independent when plotting as they were called separately. Now it is working fine. Thanks.